# GPU background processing

Tags: android, gpu, background-process

Just like CPU, does GPU also runs some processing in the background? what I want to get is the current load on the GPU. So, I would like to know if the load on GPU is completely based on what is currently displayed on the the screen or does it also has some processing going on in the background related to other apps which make use of GPU.

thanks in advance.

Comment: see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807349/live-camera-streaming-in-android