# Live Camera Streaming in Android

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera

I know how to give effect of Pencil Sketch to image but my question is different from this.

I found **Pencil Camera** app on [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ljezny.pencilcamera) which is using Live Camera Streaming in its Application.

[image]

After showing image you already know what my question will be.

**Question** : How can I achieve this?

I know about **Camera Color Effects** but it has not such option. Will **OpenCV** do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOs has GPUImage which do image processing on GPU.

**[Cyberagent](https://github.com/CyberAgent)** has created **[GPUImage for Android](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage)** which provides **GPU based Image Processing**. It provides selected image based as well Camera live filter.

Following are list of filters provided by GPU Image.

- Contrast
- Invsert
- Pixelation
- Hue
- Gamma
- Brightness
- Sepia
- GrayScale
- Sharpness
- Sobel Edge Detection
- 3x3 convolution
- Emboss
- Posterize
- Grouped Filters
- Saturation
- Exposure
- Hightlight Shadow
- Monochrome
- Opacity
- RGB
- White Balance
- Vignette
- Tone Curve
- Various Blend effects

Comment: How to capture Image using GPUImage's live Camera Preview ?

Comment: @MrSMAK its not different then Camera Preview. Simple use camera call back to capture image. It will return you byte data and you can use that.

Comment: camera preview FPS rate is too low with GPUImage

Comment: Actually, I got this library before some years. There might be some interesting GPU image library now available in market. Do you have any @AndrewF

Comment: I'm now trying to do this myself using shaders and opengl output :O Would you like to suggest some new libraries? @ChintanRathod

Comment: @AndrewF I got this.. https://android-arsenal.com/tag/47 I guess you will spend at-least a week to research which is better. :P

Comment: @ChintanRathod actualy from your link only GPUImage suppports live filters and its camera preview is too slow. https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage/issues/40